# How to solve the loop problem in database relationships?

Tags: sql, database, relationship

I have a project where users can insert auctions, tenders and advertisements. And they can also participate in auctions and tenders.
I'm having trouble designing and connecting the database and connections.
there is loop in Relationships in my database.

I have six tables called :

`user(user_id,firstName,LastName,...)`  <--all users.

`Order(order_id,user_id,OrderName,Desc,Amount,OrderType,...)` <--all ads.

```
Auction(auction_id,order_id,start_date,block_amount,min_increase,end_date,...)

Tender(tender_id,order_id,tender_base_amount,tender_start_date,tender_expire_date,...)

AuctionOffer(offer_auction_id,auction_id,user_id,auction_amount_offer,Date)

TenderOffer(tender_offer_id,tender_id,user_id,auction_amount_offer,Date)
```

My relationship:

[image]

What are your suggestions for solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any loop. All foreign keys point towards `User`.

```
CREATE TABLE [User] (
  [user_id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,,
  [user_name] VARCHAR(50),
  [first_name] VARCHAR(50),
  [last_name] VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE [Order] (
  [order_id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [user_id] INT REFERENCES [User] ( [user_id] )
  [order_name] VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE [Auction] (
  [auction_id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [order_id] INT REFERENCES [Order] ( [order_id] )
  --,...
);

CREATE TABLE [AuctionOffer] (
  [offer_auction_id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [auction_id] INT REFERENCES [Auction] ( [auction_id] ),
  [user_id] INT REFERENCES [User] ( [user_id] )
  --,...
);

CREATE TABLE [Tender] (
  [tender_id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [order_id] INT REFERENCES [Order] ( [order_id] )
  --,...
);

CREATE TABLE [TenderOffer] (
  [tender_offer_id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [tender_id] INT REFERENCES [Tender] ( [tender_id] ),
  [user_id] INT REFERENCES [User] ( [user_id] )
  ---,...
);
```

`Users` must be created first, followed by `Orders`. After that, either `Tenders` and `TenderOffers` or `Auctions` and `AuctionOffers`.

To join the tables in a query:

```
SELECT
    a.[auction_id],
    o.[order_id], o.[order_name], ou.[user_name] as [creator]
FROM [Auction] a
INNER JOIN [Order] o ON o.[order_id] = a.[order_id]
INNER JOIN [User] ou ON ou.[user_id] = o.[user_id]
;

SELECT
    aou.[user_name] as [bidder], ao.[created_date], ao.[auction_amount_offer]
FROM [AuctionOffer] ao
INNER JOIN [User] aou ON aou.[user_id] = ao.[user_id]
WHERE ao.[auction_id] = ?
ORDER BY ao.[Date] DESC
;
```

or combined:

```
SELECT
    a.[auction_id],
    o.[order_id], o.[order_name], ou.[user_name] AS [creator],
    aou.[user_name] AS [bidder], ao.[created_date], ao.[auction_amount_offer]
FROM [Auction] a
INNER JOIN [Order] o ON o.[order_id] = a.[order_id]
INNER JOIN [User] ou ON ou.[user_id] = o.[user_id]
LEFT JOIN [AuctionOffer] ao ON ao.[auction_id] = a.[auction_id] AND ao.[deleted_at] IS NULL
LEFT JOIN [User] aou ON aou.[user_id] = ao.[user_id]
ORDER BY a.[start_date], a.[start_time] a.[auction_id], ao.[created_at]
```

Notice that there are two instances of `[User]`, but with different aliases. And two columns for `[User].[user_name]`, but for different table-aliases.

Comment: I have a problem with the query. For example, I want to list all auctions (including OrderName,UserName,UserFamily, Auction_id, Amount, min_increase) along with the name and amount of the last bidder.
So I need join : order, auction, user, AuctionOffer.
The problem is that I want the name  order(whos that insert Ad) and also the last name of the bidder for it. In a record.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Markus, I do not see any M:M (many to many) relationships, 1 user can have many auction offers,tender offers and orders (1:M), 1 order can have many auctions and tenders (1:M); and 1 auction or tender can have many auction offers or tender offers (1:M). The TenderOffers and AuctionOffers tables are your 'junction tables' resolving any M:M relationships.